# How to rename Leads tab to something else in bitrix24 in free version

Tags: tags, crm, bitrix

I am using bitrix24 free version for managing CRM tasks. But we use **Enquiry** instead of **Leads**. Is there any possibility to rename "Leads" tab in bitrix24.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rename tab in cloud version of Bitrix24.